# Spring-Boot:Is there any way to add Cookies by aop

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I try to add a Cookie by aop,but it dosent work.I cant find the Cookie in Browser.
I guess the HttpServletResponse only Could be changed in a Controller.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectDemo
{
    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.controller.RestfulController.rest(..))")
    void beforeLogin(JoinPoint joinPoint)
    {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse= (HttpServletResponse) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("TestAttribute","test"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify cookie's path. If it does not help try to set httpOnly flag as well. Here is short example from my private project:

```java
newCookie.setPath("/");
newCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
newCookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
response.addCookie(newCookie);
```

Let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry,i haven't enough reputation to vote up